Weird object contours in close-up photos
when I take close-up photos I notice the pictures have a weird, unesthetical / unnatural blur, which gives harsh contours of the object. I noticed it first on the photo with flowers and now again with the one of grass. I’ve got no idea why it happens, what it is and how to correct it. It simply looks ugly to me. Below you can see photos in question with a highlight area I’m concerned about.


I use Olympus E-M10 Mark III, lenses M.Zuiko Digital 14-42mm F3.5-5.6 EZ
Parameters of the photos:
Flowers: 33mm F5.6 1/125 ISO200
Grass: 42mm F5.6 1/100 ISO 320
When taking the photo I was at or around the minimal focus distance.
Help? Thank you!

For me this looks like effect from diffraction.

Lookup "nisen bokeh"...

Could you clarify specifically what you are objecting to in the image other than that it's weird, etc. A casual observation of your images doesn't show anything in particular that is weird, etc. Thanks.

Do you find that this effect only happens to portions of the image in front of the plane of focus, and never ones behind (further away)? It is not immediately obvious in the first image, but the portion you've highlighted looks to be closer than the portion in focus. In the second image, it is apparent that the portions you've highlighted are closer than what is in focus. It is common that the behavior of the out of focus portion of the image changes in front of and behind the plane of focus.

With this lens, it's likely that you will just have to be mindful of what is in front of your plane of focus, and consider how the lens will render it. This can be a major consideration when using a soft focus lens, far less so with "fully corrected" lenses like the one that you have, but the only way to eliminate it completely may be to avoid situations where it presents itself.
To be perfectly clear, I do not think this is a problem with the lens, but a consequence of its design (and likely its low cost).

@spunky_h0rn your comments read to me like an answer.

Is this from raw? Because I bet JPEG could amplify an effect like this through artifacting.

@davolfman Anything you see on your screen has been converted from raw to a demosaiced, gamma corrected raster image that is jpeg-like and almost certainly also had at least some sharpening applied if it's not an actual jpeg preview image. It's almost always also been resized to fit the window in the application you're using or to fit your screen if you're in full screen display mode.

I see a little of what is probably nisen bokeh.
Nisen bokeh causes a bokeh doubling (outline) effect. It occurs in the foreground with an undercorrected lens, and in the background with an overcorrected lens. It also only occurs within a small range of defocus; if the focus is too great, or too blurry, then it disappears/fades. And it creates a varying degree of "business"/"harshness" in the zone where it is visible.
It is a lens (bokeh) characteristic of the lens and cannot be changed; the only thing you can do is attempt to avoid it (more/less defocus, FG/BG selection, etc).

The answer is in the specular highlights from the regions you indicated:

Instead of being uniformly lit disks or disks with a brighter middle (like a ball), those highlights, illustrating the 2-dimensional impulse response of the blurring function affecting image content in that plane, are rings with a bright outside.  This leads to blur of line features that doesn't look as much like being smudged out but rather doubled in the manner of camera shake.
As mentioned in another answer, the term for it is "nisen bokeh".
A side effect from the lens developers spending lots of attention on sharpness and flat field and non-distortion in the focusing plane.  This is a lens you buy for its sharp regions, not the unsharp ones.

In both photos problematic object is in front of sharp field. It's is almost universal property of lens that they blur foreground and background differently. If the airy disc the lens produces is not uniform then it will necessarily cause the difference between background and foreground. That's why foreground and background blur must both be evaluated in a lens review. Here's an example.

When going from foreground to background the field of sharpness is where airy disc becomes smallest possible and the outer ring  and center of airy disc are swapped. I cannot find an article about it right now.
In general you can deduce whether contours will be ugly in OOF regions by looking at airy disc pattern. You can see on your grass example that outer region of disc is bright, that's why contours are revealed through the blur.

One technique for correcting this sort of effect, along with the really shallow focal depth in macro mode, is to use focus stacking.  In focal stacking several photographs are taken with different focus distances. Some cameras will take this automatically but you can also easily take a sequence of photographs while either varying the focus slightly or moving the camera very slightly.
There are a number of tools that can build an image from a focus stack with a much wider depth of correctly focused image than a macro lens will give. Personally I find the results from the free, open source, Hugin to be excellent, (and of course it can be used for a lot of other post processing), given the price (free) I would suggest giving hugin a go.

I think what you're referring to is the colour-based artefact and not brightness-related as bokeh-balls are. It's appearing because of a limitation of the picture's colour space. The lavender has a purple colour that is outside of the sRGB gamut and it converted to a colour that is possible in sRGB. Where the lavender's colour becomes possible again, no change is made. Usually it's not visible as a change in colour is often also a change in contrast which hides the transition. In these photos, the bokeh results in mixing the purple with its surrounding colours making the change in colour fast without much contrast. This appears as an "edge". I found this blog which explains it a bit more detailed and shows what happens to the pixels in the colour space: https://codingbobby.xyz/blog/colour-clamping/
I suspect the photos you took are JPGs which are limited to sRGB. Switch your camera to RAW and the colour space will be larger (AdobeRGB for example). This makes the transition smooth out. With RAW-files you would need to edit them or at least export them as JPG with some editing software.
